# What does it mean for the determinant of $A^T A$ to be equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there any statements that are equivalent to $\det(A^T A)=0$?

Comment: $\det(A^TA)\ne 0$ iff $A$ is left-invertible iff $A$ is of full column rank ($\ker A=0$).

Answer (score 3):

At least one eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$ is equal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

The determinant of $A^TA$ equal to zero is equivalent to $A$ not invertible.

Indeed, if $A^TA$ is not invertible, there exists nonzero $x$ with $A^TAx=0$, so $x^TA^TAx=0$, which implies $Ax=0$.

Conversely, if $Ax=0$ for nonzero $x$, then $A^TAx=0$, so $A^TA$ is non-invertible.

Comment: I know. I had already edited that.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a square matrix, as $\;\det {}^{\mathrm t\!}A=\det A$,
$$\det(^{\mathrm t\!}AA)=(\det A)^2=0\iff \det A=0\iff A\enspace\text{is singular}. $$

Comment: What is $\det(A)$ for a non-square matrix $A$ like $(1,0)^T$ ?

Comment: Oops! I implicitly supposed it was a square matrix. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: No need to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\ker(A^TA)=\ker(A)$ we have directly that

> $\det(A^TA)=0$ iff $\ker(A)$ is non-trivial.